# Can I add specific elements of a double array to a stack?

Tags: arrays

I have a double char array and I need to add specific elements to a stack. The assignment is for a pacman game and the whole purpose is to create an iterative backtracking method to randomly complete the maze that i created. I can post the code that  I have(it is a lot) but I am mainly needing some direction on how to approach this. Thanks

Comment: Yes. You may access the elements from an array by their indices. If by double you mean two-dimensional, then maybe array[1][4] for example is what you will add to the stack. So, really, the problem is just writing an algorithm to access an element from an array and copy it into a stack then dealing with popping items off the stack when they are needed.

Comment: Yes you can certainly do it.